# Getting cookie Error

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have an error getting cookies from browser.

I have the following javascript cookie.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
    c = c.substring(1);
  }
  if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
}
return "";
}
```

On a different server it works like a charm, on a new server I do not receive back cookie's value. The cookie is created on same domain.

Edit:
I'm expecting to get cookie's value through this script but I am not getting it.
Is there an exception if cookie is created for www.domain.com should not be available domain.com?

I also have to mention that there is exactly the same file on both servers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Additionally, please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Check your debug tools. Look for the cookie there. You should be able to find it. If you cannot, you did not set it. Also, with the server you can set a HTTP Only cookie and JS won't be able to find it.